# File permission error when try to create files on mac os

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, file-permissions, nwjs

I created a test app on the Apple pc with Mac OS Monterey v12.0.1 in order to test the file and folder created.

However, when the file creation script runs with the **"node-main": "./index.js"** reference in the manifest file, it can not create files and gives the following permission error.

```
Error: Uncaught Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open './newfile.txt'
```

Steps followed:

Created the following files:

```
index.html
index.js
package.json
```

in the following location:
**nwjs-sdk-v0.49.1-osx-x64/nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw**

index.js file contents are as follows:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const file_name = './new-file.txt';
fs.writeFile(file_name, 'Learn NWJS', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File is created successfully.');
});
```

package.json file contents are as follows:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "node-main": "./index.js",
  "main": "./index.html"
}
```

Can anyone please help me to overcome this problem, please?

Env info:

1. OS: Mac OS Monterey v12.0.1
2. Local installed node: v14.18.1
3. NWJS: v0.49.1-sdk (downloaded zip file and extracted)

NOTE: I have given permission to the NWJS app itself and also to the app.nw folder 777 in order to see the result but the result is zero.

Thank you.

Comment: `./index.js` refers to a file in the process's working directory, which may not be where you expect. Try using an absolute path (a full path starting with `/`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the issue you are having (presume environment related). But another approach you can take that I've never had issues with is to `npm install` NW.js.

```json
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "node-main": "index.js",
  "name": "example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nw ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nw": "0.49.1-sdk"
  }
}
```

If you already have Node installed, I would recommend uninstalling it and using `nvm` (Node Version Manager) to allow you to easily switch between Node versions. NW.js comes with Node built in, so it usually works best to have the same version of Node globally installed. So being able to easily switch versions is useful.

- https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating

NW.js `0.49.1` shipped with Node `14.13.1`, so that's the version you want to globally install.

1. Update your `package.json` to the one above, put it in an empty folder with just the `index.html` and `index.js` files next to it on your desktop.
2. Install `nvm`
3. Run `nvm install 14.13.1`
4. Check your Node version matches with `node -v`
5. Check that you have npm with `npm -v` (should come with Node)
6. Run `npm install && npm start` from the folder with your `package.json`

That will download NW.js to a `node_modules` folder for you and run it. Any time you want to run it again you just need `npm start`.